# FileMaker Server new added record to trigger php script

Tags: php, triggers, filemaker

We would like to call a php script from a filemaker server as soon as a new record is inserted

Something like a onChange event to be fired when someone add a new booking, or modify it; the idea is to sync an already existing FileMaker Server bookings database with Checkfront (http://www.checkfront.com/) through their API.
We came across script triggers; but we understand they are only available for FileMaker pro and we would like to be using the Filemaker server. We also noted some plugins like Troi's Activator (http://www.troi.com/software/activatorplugin.html) but it seems we don't have the right terminology and are not sure if this do the job…

Can someone point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping this will help someone and spare a couple of hours digging painfully the FM documentation: there is no way to implement and control the inventory on the FileMaker side the way we thought or planned initially.

We instead used an ODBC driver to connect directly the Mysql database to the FileMaker application; the mysql tables are then used exactly as if they were native to the FileMaker environnement.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is typically handled by setting up a Schedule on FileMaker Server to run a script periodically, say, every minute. The script you call in FileMaker might look for all new records (records where some newRecord flag was set on creation), run your PHP sync, then remove the newRecord flag.

Comment: thanks; this would mean we then might run into trouble with the time lapse of polling… and double booking via the web and offline (operator using filemaker)

when you say Schedule with a capital S: is it a feature of FMserver?(or is it a cron job on apache)

Comment: On FileMaker Server you can schedule scripts to be run in a FM database. Ex: you could have a script that does a "find" of all records that need to be submitted to the API and have it process them. Scheduled scripts are synchronous so you won't have issues with the process running on the same recordset at the same time.